# Phonegap Windows phone ajax call is not working

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I have created windows phone app through phonegap and i have deployed in windows phone using application deployment tool and it is working well ( all functions including ajax call ). After that i have uploaded in windows store.

Now , Ajax call is not working when that app installed from store. but it is working in deployment. 
In `config.xml` file 
Permissions :

```
<preference name="permissions" value="INTERNET" /> 
<preference name="permissions" value="ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<preference name="permissions" value="ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 
<preference name="permissions" value="WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<preference name="permissions" value="READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Plugins :

```
<gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" version="4.3.8" />
<gap:plugin name="com.indigoway.cordova.whitelist.whitelistplugin" version="1.1.1" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.Device" />
```

Feautures :

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
```

How can i resolve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have added below code and finally worked out that ajax call in the app which is downloaded from windows store.

```
$(document).on( "mobileinit", function() {  
  $.support.cors = true;  
  $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;  
});
```